# 404 error in magento module

Tags: php, magento, mysqli, magento-1.6

*i new in magento*

**add column or field in customer group using module and another module as like as product with add, edit or delete option**

i search for this but doesn't find the specific answer how to done this with module because all answer about edit the magento inbuilt files

so Please tell me how to create a module which add a field in customer group at admin panel, store the value and how to retrive this value at frontend using php

i try to make a module and here my files are

app/code/local/super/awesome/

etc/config.xml

```
<config>
<modules>
    <Super_Awesome>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Super_Awesome>
</modules>
<adminhtml>
    <!-- The <layout> updates allow us to define our block layouts in a seperate file so are aren't messin' with the magento layout files.  -->
    <layout>
        <updates>
            <awesome>
                <file>awesome.xml</file>
            </awesome>
        </updates>
    </layout>
    <!-- The <acl> section is for access control. Here we define the pieces where access can be controlled within a role. -->
    <acl>
        <resources>
            <admin>
                <children>
                    <awesome>
                        <title>Awesome Menu Item</title>
                        <children>
                            <example translate="title" module="awesome">
                                <title>Example Menu Item</title>
                            </example>
                        </children>
                    </awesome>
                </children>
            </admin>
        </resources>
    </acl>
</adminhtml>
<admin>
    <!--
        Here we are telling the Magento router to look for the controllers in the Super_Awesome_controllers_Adminhtml before we look in the
        Mage_Adminhtml module for all urls that begin with /admin/controller_name
     -->
    <routers>
        <adminhtml>
            <args>
                <modules>
                    <awesome before="Mage_Adminhtml">Super_Awesome_Adminhtml</awesome>
                </modules>
            </args>
        </adminhtml>
    </routers>
</admin>

<global>
    <models>
        <awesome>
            <class>Super_Awesome_Model</class>
            <resourceModel>awesome_mysql4</resourceModel>
        </awesome>
         <awesome_mysql4>
            <class>Super_Awesome_Model_Mysql4</class>
            <entities>
                <example>
                    <table>Super_Awesome_example</table>
                </example>
            </entities>
        </awesome_mysql4>
    </models>

    <resources>
        <awesome_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>Super_Awesome</module>
            </setup>
            <connection>
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </awesome_setup>
        <awesome_write>
            <connection>
                <use>core_write</use>
            </connection>
        </awesome_write>
        <awesome_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </awesome_read>
    </resources>

    <blocks>
        <awesome>
            <class>Super_Awesome_Block</class>
        </awesome>
    </blocks>
    <helpers>
        <awesome>
            <class>Super_Awesome_Helper</class>
        </awesome>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

etc/adminhtml.xml

```
<config>
<menu>
    <awesome translate="title" module="awesome">
        <title>Awesome</title>
        <sort_order>15</sort_order>
        <children>
            <example translate="title" module="awesome">
                <title>Example</title>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                <action>adminhtml/example/index</action>
            </example>
        </children>
    </awesome>
</menu>
```

Helper/Data.php

```
class Super_Awesome_Helper_Data extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract{}
```

sql/awesome_setup/mysql4-install-0.1.0.php

```
$installer = $this;$installer->startSetup();$installer->run("");$installer->endSetup();
```

Please tell me next steps for the module

Please help me, and thanks

Comment: You have explained more about how much you are new to magento rather than the question ! what is the requirement ? What is the question ?

Comment: And question title doesn't match to what you described here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Logout/login again
- Make sure you have ACL defined for the menu items in the XML config of your module.

---

Your menu in config should look like this

```
<menu>
    <custommodule translate="title" module="custommodule">
        <title>Custom Module</title>
        <sort_order>100</sort_order>
        <children>
            <custommodule translate="title" module="custommodule">
                <title>Custom Module</title>
                <sort_order>101</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <custommodule1 translate="title" module="custommodule">
                        <title>Custom Module1</title>
                        <action>custommodule/adminhtml_event</action>
                        <sort_order>102</sort_order>
                    </custommodule1>

                </children>
            </custommodule>
        </children>
    </custommodule>
</menu>
```

And ACL in config.xml ( or admintml ) should look like this:

```
<acl>
    <resources>
        <all>
            <title>Allow Everything</title>
        </all>
        <admin>

            <children>
                <custommodule translate="title" module="custommodule">
                    <title>Custom Module</title>
                    <sort_order>100</sort_order>

                    <children>
                        <custommodule translate="title">
                            <title>Custom Module</title>
                            <sort_order>101</sort_order>
                            <children>
                                <custommodule1 translate="title" module="custommodule">
                                    <title>Custom Module1</title>
                                </custommodule1>

                            </children>
                        </custommodule>
                    </children>
                </custommodule>

            </children>
        </admin>
    </resources>
</acl>
```

Comment: Definitely your comments will make him more confused. He seems to be totally new and might not be knowing about ACL.:)

Comment: yes agree with you. :)

Comment: yeh i m new but i try it as u said but its not working, when i click on the sub menu it will open the frontend page which show the 404 error. 
i try to make a menu this part is completed but when click on the menu it show the page as product page in the backend so please help me in this

Comment: Paste your config.xml ?

Comment: i add files above you can check file from above. please tell me how to do this

Comment: Check the XML example and follow it, it should fix your issue ( you have missing tags )